# Remove cols and rows from 2d matrix if all their values are equal

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, matrix

1. My matrix / 2d array looks like this.  *** | ***
2. I want to get this result

   ```
          |                                |
          Y                                Y

   [                                 
      [0,0,0,0],                     [
      [0,1,0,2],        --->           [1,0,2],
      [0,2,3,0],                       [2,3,0],
      [0,5,0,0]                        [5,0,0]
   ]                                 [
   ```

   I'd like to remove all rows / cols if their values are ALL equal.

   ```
   0 1 2 3 4
   1 A A A A      --> remove col 1
   2 B B B B
   3 B X B C
   4 A B O B



   0 1 2 3 4
   1 A A C A      
   2 B B C B
   3 B X C C
   4 A B C B
         |
         |
         Y
     remove row 3
   ```

My idea was to use a function like you can find below but my code doesn't seems to work.

Checking "*equality*" for the X-direction works with no problems, but I have no clue what's the problem with the Y-direction. Obviously it's not working that well :p

my function:

```js
var myarray=[
  [0,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0]
]

remove_equal_rows(myarray)
function remove_equal_rows(array) {
  /*
    x direction --> (working)
  */
  var statusX=true;
  for (var i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      if (array[i][j] !== array[i][0]) {
        statusX=false;break;
      } else statusX=true
    }
    console.log('remove col "'+i+'": ' + statusX)
  }

  console.log('-------')

  /*
    y direction --> (not working)            
  */
  var statusY=true;
  for (var i=0;i<array[0].length;i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      if (array[j][i] !== array[j][0]) {
        statusY=false;break;
      } else statusY=true
    }
    console.log('remove row "'+i+'": ' + statusY)
  }
}
```

Comment: Who should be removed first: a row or a column? (as removing a column may yield to a new matrix that need a row to be removed and vice-versa). Or should the removal of columns and rows be independ (using the original matrix as a reference)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Independent removal of rows and columns:**

Remove the columns and rows while using the original unaltered matrix as reference:

```js
function remove(matrix) {
    let newMatrix = matrix.filter(row => row.some(e => e != row[0]))  // filter the rows that have different values
                          .map(row => row.slice(0));                  // copy them into newMatrix (so the original matrix isn't affected by altering them (the rows))
    
    if(newMatrix.length === 0) return newMatrix;                      // if newMatrix turned out to be rowless (then just retrun it without attempting to clean the columns)
    
    for(var i = newMatrix[0].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {               // for each column (looping backwards so that removing  column won't affect the index i)
        var first = matrix[0][i];                                     // getting the value of the i-th column of the first row
        if(matrix.every(row => row[i] === first)) {                   // if all rows have the same value as first for the i-th column
          newMatrix.forEach(row => row.splice(i, 1));                 // then remove the i-th item (column) from each row
        }
    }
    
    return newMatrix;
}

var result = remove([
  [0,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0],
  [1,0,5,0],
  [1,0,0,0]
]);

console.log(result.join("\n"));
```

**Dependent removal of rows and columns**:

Depending on the order of removing either rows or columns, one may get different results:

```js
/* Same code as before except that we now have different functions:
 *   removeRows: that take a matrix and remove rows that have the same values
 *   removeColumns: that take a matrix and remove columns that have the same values
 * depending on wether to call removeRows or removeColumns, you may get different results as shown in an example bellow. (You my call removeRows then removeColumns then call removeRows again and get a different result et cetera...)
 */

function removeRows(matrix) {
  return matrix.filter(row => row.some(e => e != row[0]));
}

function removeColumns(matrix) {
  if (matrix.length === 0) return matrix;

  for (var i = matrix[0].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var first = matrix[0][i];
    if (matrix.every(row => row[i] === first)) {
      matrix.forEach(row => row.splice(i, 1));
    }
  }

  return matrix;
}

console.log("Removeing rows then columns:");

var result = removeRows([
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 5, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0]
]);

result = removeColumns(result);

console.log(result.join("\n"));

console.log("Removeing columns then rows:");

var result = removeColumns([
  [0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 5, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0]
]);

result = removeRows(result);

console.log(result.join("\n"));
```

**Notes:**

1. To check if a row has different values, I used `some` to check if there is some other value in the row that is different from the first element in the row.
2. To check if a column `i` has the same values, I used `every` to check that the `i-th` element of every row is equal to the `i-th` element of the first row.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Looks absolutely well!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you were checking the rows **again** in the second pair of loops. I'm pretty sure this is how it should have been written.

```
var statusY=true;
for (var i=0;i<array[0].length;i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j < array.length; j++) {
    if (array[j][i] !== array[0][i]) {
      statusY=false;break;
    } else statusY=true
  }
  console.log('remove row "'+i+'": ' + statusY)
}
```

Comment: Absolutely true. Thanks D:

Answer (score 0):

You can the rows by using [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and converting each array to a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). If the size of the set is 1, the array should be removed.

To filter the columns, it's easier to rebuild the grid from scratch. Iterate the 1st row with [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b). As accumulator initialize a new grid using [Array#from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). For each column create a Set from the original column (before filtering the rows), if the size of the set is greater than 0, push it's items to the new grid using [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
const myarray = [
  [0,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0]
];

const filteredRows = myarray.filter((arr) => new Set(arr).size !== 1); // if a the set of the row contains only 1 item it should be remove

const filteredColumns = (filteredRows[0] || []).reduce((r, _, i) => { // iterate the 1st row
  const keep = new Set(myarray.map((arr) => arr[i])).size > 1; // if a the set of the column in the original grid contains more than 1 item, it should be kept
  
  
  keep && filteredRows.forEach((arr, j) => r[j].push(arr[i])); // if we keep it, and the column to the grid
  
  return r;
}, Array.from({ length: filteredRows.length }, () => [])); // initialize with an empty grid

console.log(filteredColumns);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: (first row 0 will be removed then col0 and col 2 will be removed)

```
var myarray=[
  [0,0,0,0],
  [1,0,2,0],
  [1,1,2,1],
  [1,0,2,0]
]

remove_equal_rows(myarray)
function remove_equal_rows(myArray) {
  /*
    x direction --> (working)
  */

  var resultX = [];

  for (var i=0; i<myArray.length;i++) {
    statusX = true;
    for (var j = 1; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
      if (myArray[i][j] !== myArray[i][0]) {
        statusX=false;break;
      }
    }
    if (statusX) { resultX.push(i); }
  }
  console.log('rows indexes to remove : ', resultX);
  resultX.map(function(item) { myArray.splice(item,1); });

  console.log('-------', myArray);
  /*
    y direction --> (now working)            
  */
  var statusY, resultY = [];
  for (var i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
    statusY = true;
    for (var j = 1; j < myArray.length; j++) {
      console.log(j, i, myArray[j][i]);
      if (myArray[j][i] !== myArray[0][i]) {
        statusY=false;break;
      }
    }
    if (statusY) {resultY.push(i);}
  }
  console.log('cols indexes to remove : ', resultY);
  resultY.map(function(item) { myArray.splice(item,1); });

  console.log('-------', myArray);
}
```

checkout this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a9qvtuu4/

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this recursively where it runs the result array through the uniqueifier repeatedly until no modifications are made.

Making the X-direction rows distinct is more straightforward than columns, so you can handle distinct columns by rotating the matrix -> distinct X-direction -> rotate back.

```js
var masterArr = [
  [0,0,0,0],
  [1,0,0,0],
  [1,0,3,0],
  [1,0,0,4]
];

function uniqueColRow(arr) {
  if(arr.length === 0 || arr[0].length === 0) {
    return arr;
  }

  var distinctRows = arr.filter((x) => { return x.filter(unique).length > 1;  });  
  
  var flip = rotateArr(distinctRows);
  
  var distinctCols = flip.filter((x) => { return x.filter(unique).length > 1;  });  
  
  var resultArr = rotateArr(distinctCols);
  
  if(arr.length !== resultArr.length || arr[0].length !== resultArr[0].length) {    
    console.log('running again with:');
    console.log(resultArr);
    return uniqueColRow(resultArr);
  }else {
    return resultArr;
  }
}

console.log('Original:');
console.log(masterArr);
console.log('\n');

var result = uniqueColRow(masterArr);

console.log('\nFinal:')
console.log(result);

function rotateArr(arr) {
   return arr[0].map((col, i) => arr.map(row => row[i]));
}

function unique(item, i, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(item) === i;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L34jatuw/) has slightly easier to read console output.

Great question - fun puzzle!

Comment: Thanks a lot for you're answer. I will study your code later :)